# How to get six digit pin number using Twitterizer for Desktop Application

Tags: c#-4.0, twitter, desktop, twitter-oauth, twitterizer

To get this i reference Twitterizer2 library and user below code based on this guideline http://www.twitterizer.net/tutorials/getting-started-with-oauth

```
      OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken("consumer key", "consumer secret");
```

but i don't see that GetRequestToken is taking only two parameters. It expects additional parameter for call bacl-url. In my case i am getting accessToken and accessSecret from client mobile app via service and then using Twitterizer library i post the tweet. Not sure if i need to user accessSecret or pin for below call

```
  var service = new TwitterService();
  service.AuthenticateWith(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret);
  service.SendTweet(TweetMessage);
```

Is there any alternative to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the 6 digit pin number, you have to set your callback URL to `oob`.